# JavaScript Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript

I have the following line:

```
var $testDiv = $(("<div class='ui-jqgrid' style='left:10000px'><table class='ui-jqgrid-btable' style='width:5px;'><tr class='jqgrow'><td style='width:5px;'></td></tr></table></div>"), testCell = $testDiv.appendTo("body").find("td").width(); $testDiv.remove();
```

And I have no clue which `;` is being referenced by this error - do any of you see something I'm missing?

**Edit 1**

for completeness, here is the surrounding code:

```
...
jqID: function (f) {
                f += "";
                return f.replace(/([\.\:\[\]])/g, "\\$1")
            },
            cellWidth: function () {
                var $testDiv = $(("<div class='ui-jqgrid' style='left:10000px'><table class='ui-jqgrid-btable' style='width:5px;'><tr class='jqgrow'><td style='width:5px;'></td></tr></table></div>"), testCell = $testDiv.appendTo("body").find("td").width(); $testDiv.remove();
                    return testCell !== 5
                },
                    ajaxOptions: {}, extend: function (f) {
                        b.extend(b.fn.jqGrid, f);
                        this.no_legacy_api || b.fn.extend(f)
                    }
            });
...
```

Comment: Put code on multiple lines, then run in browser with dev tools to get info on error line.

Comment: why there is two **((** here $**((**"<div ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an additional `(`, **remove it**

Use

```
 var $testDiv = $("<div
```

instead of

```
 var $testDiv = $(("<div
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var $testDiv = $(("..html here ..."), testCell = $testDiv.appendTo("body").find("td").width();
                ab                 b           a?????
```

You're missing a `)` somewhere. You open two, but only close one.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket

```
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this in the middle:

```
</table></div>"),
```

Did you intend for this to be a comma? This might be better:

```
var $testDiv = $("<div class='ui-jqgrid' style='left:10000px'><table class='ui-jqgrid-btable' style='width:5px;'><tr class='jqgrow'><td style='width:5px;'></td></tr></table></div>"); testCell = $testDiv.appendTo("body").find("td").width(); $testDiv.remove();
```

or even better:

```
var $testDiv = $("<div class='ui-jqgrid' style='left:10000px'><table class='ui-jqgrid-btable' style='width:5px;'><tr class='jqgrow'><td style='width:5px;'></td></tr></table></div>");
testCell = $testDiv.appendTo("body").find("td").width();
$testDiv.remove();
```

There's value in not running everything into a single line - you can READ it.